# How to make Android phone as my wireless dialer, so that i can dial the phone and send / receive SSH, FTP etc?

Tags: calls, linux, remote-control, phone-app, dialer-codes

How can i make the Android mobile phone number +3900000 as incoming dialing number from computer running Linux (ArchLinux, Fedora, CentOS, Ubuntu) using modem. Once the connection is made.  How is it possible to send / receive packets from mobile  to that local network or use SSH/FTP in that location?

Just a device for remote assistance services (like to avoid VPN/ETC ETC).

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to establish a dial-up service on your Android device -- or would a solution which starts the appropriate service on an incoming call suffice (that is, provided the computers themselves already have a network connection -- though in that case, all traffic would be routed via "open internet", but you could use secure protocols such as SSH)?

Comment: @Izzy: dial up service like from another PC using modem dial in to the mobile number. Once connected/connection established. Then browse that LAN for remote assistence maintainence.

Comment: I see. So it's about "emulating a VPN". Never heard of a working solution for this, so I'm out. Good luck, though -- but I'm afraid there is no such thing available.